# Python: not able to plot more than one graph

Tags: python, graph

I am trying to plot multiple graphs using for loop and primary `key ="business_id"` Its a json file.

here is my code:
it plots just the first graph i.e for the first business id only and not for the remaining id. How can i make it work for all the ids

```
data=f.read()
jsondata=json.loads(data)
z=[]
for row in jsondata['rows']:
    id=row['business_id']
    print id

for i in id:

    for row in jsondata['rows']:
    y= row['checkin_info']
    x=int(y['one p.m'])
    x2=int(y['two p.m'])
    x3=int(y['three p.m'])
    x4=int(y['four p.m'])
    x5=int(y['five p.m'])
    x6=int(y['six p.m'])
    x7=int(y['seven p.m'])
    x8=int(y['eight p.m'])
    x9=int(y['nine p.m'])
    x10=int(y['ten p.m'])
    x11=int(y['eleven p.m'])
    x12=int(y['twelve p.m'])
    z.append(x)
    z.append(x2)
    z.append(x3)
    z.append(x4)
    z.append(x5)
    z.append(x6)
    z.append(x7)
    z.append(x8)
    z.append(x9)
    z.append(x10)
    z.append(x11)
    z.append(x12)


    time_slots=["one p.m","two p.m","three p.m","four p.m","five 
        p.m","six p.m","seven p.m","eight p.m","nine   
        p.m","ten.pm","eleven p.m","twelve p.m"]
    pylab.figure(1)
    x = range(12)
    pylab.xticks(x, time_slots)
    pylab.plot(x,z,"g")

    pylab.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, your json-file structure isn't clear for me. And maybe you missed some indentation levels in your code. Therefore, I suggest several solutions. If you must go through all id's, then it could be better to store id's in list:

```
ids=[]
for row in jsondata['rows']:
    id=row['business_id']
    ids.append(id)
    print id
```

Second option: your figures must be numbered and show() function must be outside the for loop

```
for i, id in enumerate(ids):
    ...
    pylab.figure(i)
    ...
pylab.show()
```